# Undefined reference to class methods

Tags: c++

I have three files method.h,method.cpp,main.cpp

method.h

```
#ifndef METHOD_H
#define METHOD_H

class method {

public:
       void printThisMethod();
private:

};

#endif
```

method.cpp

```
#include "method.h"
inline void method::printThisMethod() {
    //some methods done here
}
```

main.cpp

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include "method.h"

 int main() {
     method outputMethod;
     outputMethod.printThisMethod;
 }
```

I am getting the error,

```
undefined reference to method::printThisMethod.
```

Please help thanks

Comment: Remove the inline keyword.

Comment: A link error? How do you build this?

Comment: if i remove it I will have the error multiple definition of method::printThisMethod() as I did used "printThisMethod" in some of my functions as well other than main

Comment: Any other files in your project?

Comment: A class called "method". Sure, that makes buckets of sense...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either remove the `inline` keyword, or move the definition into the header (keeping the `inline`).

`inline` is used to relax the One Definition Rule to allow definitions in headers. However, it also *requires* a definition in every translation unit that uses it, which often requires the definition to be in a header.

Without `inline`, normal linkage rules apply, and there must be a single definition in one translation unit. That is what you'll have, if you remove `inline` from your existing code.

(You also need to add parentheses to the function call, `outputMethod.printThisMethod()`, but presumably your real code has them, otherwise it wouldn't get as far as the link error.)

Comment: if i remove it I will have the error multiple definition of method::printThisMethod() as I did used "printThisMethod" in some of my functions as well other than main

Comment: @user3193812: You shouldn't get that error, since you only define it in a single source file. (Unless you do something crazy like including that source file instead of the header - but your example certainly isn't doing anything like that).

Comment: but that's what I saw on the output from my netbeans 7.4

Comment: @user3193812: In that case, you've got a different problem, which isn't represented by the code you've posted. You'll get a multiple definition error if it's defined in a header without `inline`, or if you actually have a second definition somewhere, or if you're `#include`ing the source file somewhere when you meant to include the header. You won't if you have a single definition in one source file (and no crazy includes).

Comment: alright I think I rewrote everything. I turns out fine now. thanks for your advice and help

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
outputMethod.printThisMethod;
```

to

```
outputMethod.printThisMethod();
```

Comment: Also remove the 'inline' keyword from method.cpp. If you want to use inline a class member you have to put it in the header.